# How to show a vector space is a real form of another?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

I only know from the definition that, say $V_1$ is a real form of $V$, if $V=\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} V_1$, but what does this really mean? Is it true it is just saying that $V$ is spanned by vectors of $V_1$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

For example, if I want to show that $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is a real form of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, what exactly am I suppose to check?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are many confusing, or potentially confusing items in what you write. First, $A$ is a real form of $B$ can mean "$B$ is isomorphic to the complexification of $A$". But furthermore if $A\subset B$, it can also mean the stronger: the inclusion $A\subset B$ induces an isomorphism from the complexification of $A$ to $B$. Second, you're talking about being real form as vector space, but most likely you want to have a real form as algebra, which is a stronger fact.

Comment: In any case, if you have a complex algebra $B$, a real subalgebra $A\subset B$ such that $B=A\oplus iA$, then you have the strongest version: the inclusion induces an isomorphism from the complexification to $B$. So all you need here is to show that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbf{C})=\mathfrak{su}(n)\oplus i\mathfrak{su}(n)$. Since the real dimension of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is half the real dimension of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbf{C})$, it's enough to check that $\mathfrak{su}(n)\cap i\mathfrak{su}(n)=\{0\}$, and this is very easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition $V = V_1 \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$ is a complex vector space whose elements are formal linear combinations of pairs $(v, z) \in V \times \Bbb C$ modulo the usual identifications of tensor products, including in particular the the equivalence relation $(a v, z) \sim (v, a z)$, $a \in \Bbb R$. We denote the image of a single pair $(v, z)$ under this related by $v \otimes z$. Then, if $(E_1, \ldots, E_n)$ is a basis of $V_1$, then $(E_1 \otimes 1, \ldots, E_n \otimes 1)$ is a basis of $V_1 \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$, but often by abuse of notation we write this latter basis again as $(E_1, \ldots, E_n)$.

Given a complex vector space $\Bbb V$, one way to construct a real form thereof is to pick a complex-*anti*linear involution $\phi : \Bbb V \to \Bbb V$---here involution just means that $\phi^2 = 1_{\Bbb V}$. Then, the fixed point set $$\Bbb V^{\phi} = \{{\bf v} \in \Bbb V : \phi({\bf v}) = {\bf v}\}$$---which is a *real* vector space---is a real form of $\Bbb V$.

Conversely, all real forms arise this way: Given a real vector space $\Bbb W$, the conjugation map characterized by $$\phi({\bf w} \otimes z) := {\bf w} \otimes \bar z$$ is an antilinear involution of the complexification $\Bbb W \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$, and its fixed point set $(\Bbb W \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C)^{\phi}$ is the (real) span of the vectors ${\bf w} \otimes 1$. Respectively identifying these vectors with ${\bf w} \in \Bbb W$ defines a natural isomorphism $(\Bbb W \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C)^{\phi} \cong \Bbb W$. Similarly, if the real vector space $\Bbb W$ is a real form of the complex vector space $\Bbb V$, then there is a (complex) vector space isomorphism $\Bbb V \cong \Bbb W \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$.

For example, we usually identify $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ as the space of $n \times n$ matrices that (1) are skew-Hermitian, that is, satisfy $X^\dagger = -X$, and (2) have zero trace (over $\Bbb C$), that is, are in $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb C)$. Rearranging the condition in (1) gives that these matrices are precisely the matrices in $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb C)$ fixed by the map $\phi : X \mapsto -X^\dagger$. This is an antilinear involution, so $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb C)^{\phi} = \mathfrak{su}(n)$, that is, (the underlying vector space of) $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is a real form of (the underlying vector space of) $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb C)$.

*Remark* In the previous paragraph we said that the vector space underlying one real Lie algebra was a real form of the vector space underlying a certain complex Lie algebra. This extra verbiage is a priori necessary, because in the context of Lie algebras we usually reserve the terminology *real form* for when the conjugation operation is also compatible with the Lie algebra structure. In terms of the antilinear map $\phi$, this additional requirement is that $\phi$ is a (real) Lie algebra homomorphism, that is, that $\phi([X, Y]) = [\phi(X), \phi(Y)]$. This condition holds for the map $\phi$ in the example in the previous paragraph, so we conclude that $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is a real form of the $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb C)$ in this stronger sense, too.

Comment: hi, this is very useful. however, at the end of the first paragraph, should the definition of the basis of the complexification include also tensor products with $i$ in addition to $1$? thanks

Comment: @l4teLearner In that context I'm referring to complex vector spaces, and the basis $\{E_a \otimes 1\}$ is a basis of $V$ as written. If we forget the complex structure and so regard $V$ as a real vector space of dimension $2 n$, and so to write down a basis of the latter we'd need another $n$ vectors. Like you suggest, the vectors $E_a \otimes i$ are a natural choice.